# Modificar atributo varchar

Tags: mysql, sql

Necesito modificar un atributo de `varchar(9)` a `varchar(15)`, me da error de sintaxis, pero no veo el fallo...

Modificar el tipo de dato de la División de los equipos a un `VARCHAR (15)` y que admita **valores nulos**
(la tabla es equipos, el atributo Division)

```
alter table equipos change column Division varchar(15) null;
```

---

Comment: La columna división que tipo de dato es justo ahorita antes de hacer el cambio?

Comment: Ya lo tengo para que admita valores nulos, pero es tipo varchar (9) y tengo que pasarlo a varchar(15)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La sentencia pudiera quedar así:

```
alter table equipos MODIFY column Division varchar(15) null;
```

Es decir la sintaxis requiere de:

- `MODIFY` Para indicar que la columna será modificada en su estructura
- `column` La palabra reservada para indicar que se altera la estructura de una columna
- `NULL` Que será el atributo que indique que admite nulos
- `VARCHAR(15)` Para indicar que la longitud del campo de tipo `VARCHAR` aumenta de 9 a 15

**Es importante considerar que**:

Este cambio solo se va a poder aplicar si:

- Los tipos de datos que ya estan almacenados no entran en conflicto con el tipo de dato que se asignará, (es decir que no sean incompatibles con el nuevo que deseas establecer para almacenar)
- Si la longitud que se declara no es menor a la que ocupan los valores que actualmente estan almacenados, ya que de serlo tus datos pudieran quedar *truncados* al no *caber* en la nueva asignación.

**Referencias**

- [mysql alter table modify](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table-examples.html)

Comment: Gracias! parece que era con modify

Answer (score 0):

Te sobra el **column** ysustituirlo por el nombre de la columna

```
alter table equipos change Division Division varchar(15) null;
```

Probado en mi phpmyadmin con una tabla llamada 'letras' y un campo llamado 'letra':

```
ALTER TABLE `letras` CHANGE `letra` `letra` CHAR(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL;
```